# How to use ITG-3500 evb

Tags: sensors

[image: Picture of the boards]

I am trying to make motion capture and someone gave me these boards.

I think it's a test board for MPU 9500. I tried to google but I only found datasheets. What boards are these?

"ITG-3500 evb" is written on the back of the green board.
I think this is [datasheet](http://store.invensense.com/datasheets/invensense/AN-IVS-0001EVB-00-v1-2.pdf) of green board maybe

"EV_ARM_XXAXA_D" is written on the back of the blue board.

Comment: You mentioned that you found some datasheets - could you edit your answer to include the links, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had to, briefly, play with these boards a while back, and although I used different revisions and versions of the boards, they are probably the same functionally. Unfortunately, I don't have any of my old notes as I have moved country. Regardless...

As Majenko says in his [answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/20286/how-to-use-itg-3500-evb#answer-20287) the green board is an evaluation board for the ITG-3500 3-axis gyroscope, which is presumably the SMD chip (in a QFN format) mounted on it, in the lower part of the board (looking at your photo). A [data sheet on the *similar* ITG-3200](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Gyro/PS-ITG-3200-00-01.4.pdf) (note *not* the evaluation board itself)  can be found on SparkFun. To quote part of the product description:

> The ITG-3200 is the world’s first single-chip, digital-output, 3-axis
> MEMS gyro IC optimized for gaming, 3D mice, and 3D remote control
> applications. The part features enhanced bias and sensitivity
> temperature stability, reducing the need for user calibration. Low
> frequency noise is lower than previous generation devices, simplifying
> application development and making for more-responsive remote
> controls.
>
> The ITG-3200 features three 16-bit analog-to-digital
> converters (ADCs) for digitizing the gyro outputs, a user-selectable
> internal low-pass filter bandwidth, and a Fast-Mode I2C (400kHz)
> interface. Additional features include an embedded temperature sensor
> and a 2% accurate internal oscillator. This breakthrough in gyroscope
> technology provides a dramatic 67% package size reduction, delivers a
> 50% power reduction, and has inherent cost advantages compared to
> competing multi-chip gyro solutions.

In addition, in case it is of any use, here is the [datasheet for the, again similar, ITG-3701](http://store.invensense.com/datasheets/invensense/PS-ITG-3701.pdf), which I located on the [Digi sales site](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/ITG-3701/1428-1050-1-ND/5015524). Frustratingly, I am unable to locate a datasheet for the ITG-3500 - however, you mentioned that you found some datasheets - could you edit your answer to include the links, please?

The Blue board is a "Gyroscope Evaluation Board: EV_INV-ARM" manufactured by InvenSense Inc., and to quote its [product description](http://store.invensense.com/ProductDetail/EVINVARMG-InvenSense-Inc/425140/):

> The InvenSense ARM reference board provides a bridge function between InvenSense evaluation boards and a PC. It connects to a PC via USB and to InvenSense evaluation boards via SPI or I2C. The ARM processor on the reference board is not meant to be reprogrammed by the user. It contains all code necessary to be used in conjunction InvenSense evaluation boards. (Note that separate demonstration software may accompany the individual evaluation boards with which this device connects.)

Here is a link to the [EV_INV-ARM DataSheet](http://store.invensense.com/datasheets/invensense/AN-000039%20v1.0.pdf). The Atmel chip on it is possibly the AT91SAM7SE512 MCU, and here is a link to its [product specification](http://www.atmel.com/devices/SAM7SE512.aspx).

Software wise, you may find this [Linux kernel driver for the ITG-3500](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/tegra.git/+/eb72d0308d4f46ff106f7097a3c040cfda83733d/drivers/staging/iio/imu/inv_mpu/README) extremely useful.

---

#### TL;DR

It seems like you need to get hold of the separate demonstration software for the ITG-3500 evaluation board, according to the EV-INV_ARM's product description, in order to *easily* make it do something.

Comment: i edit it  
I'm not sure that is correct datasheet. but picture of board is same

Comment: i read both of data sheet. but i can't understand the EV_INV-ARM.   
In datasheet it mentioned **reference board is not meant to be reprogrammed by user.**
then this board is just used as connect gyrscope board(ITG-3500) with pc?

Comment: @jen6 that is what I understood as well. It is purely a communication medium to use with the evb

Answer (score 1):

The green board is an ITG-3500 (3 axis gyroscope) evaluation board of some form.

The blue board is some form of microcontroller evaluation board. It probably has one of the Atmel SAM chips on it since it mentions ARM.

That's about all you'll get from us I'm afraid, unless there is the highly unlikely situation that someone here happens to have the exact same boards as you.

Comment: can i upload program at blue board like atmega128?

Comment: I would imagine so, otherwise it would be useless. The real question is *how* do you do that. There appears to be a JTAG connection that could be used, but that is all I can tell you. Read what the chip is (it has numbers and letters on it), find a compatible JTAG programmer, and the right software, and you're half way there.